# maven fails to resolve jar dependency when skipTest property set

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I have a multi-module maven project which has a pom file with packaging type as `jar` as described below. Another module in the project depends on this `jar`. When executing command `mvn clean install`, everything works fine but when executing `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`, the project throws an error complaining unable to resolve dependency for the jar.

```
<artifactId>project.artifact.id</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Project Name</name>
<description>Project Description</description>

<dependencies>
   .... 
</dependencies>
```

Do I need to include some jar plugin or any other workaround for the same ?

Comment: Which jar causes the error? What are the full contents of that pom?

Comment: Can you give us the full `pom.xml`? This would make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to version mismatch. Verify the versions of dependencies included and check for any conflicting dependency versions.

Comment: You're saying that based on what?